# How to get a cell value buttonclick in DataGrid C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to display a particular cell  value a row in a `ShowRichMessageBox` when i click on the `button` but this event display the cell value if click anywhere on the row....!

what is wrong here.....How can I fix the above problem???

I have some logvalues which are big but it's already loaded in the cell so,
`Is it possible to expand the row when i select a particular row in the datagridview???`

```
 public LogView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView2.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView2_buttonCol);

        bindingList = new SortedBindingList<ILogItemView>();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingList;
        this.dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridView2.MultiSelect = false;
        var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn(); // The button to display a particular cell value when clicks//
        buttonCol.Name = "ButtonColumnName";
        buttonCol.HeaderText = "Show";
        buttonCol.Text = "View";
        buttonCol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;    
        dataGridView2.Columns.Add(buttonCol);

    }

    private void dataGridView2_buttonCol(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            string name = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
            ShowRichMessageBox("Code", name);

    }
```

Edit:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) // Change to the index of your button column
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                string name = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
                ShowRichMessageBox("Code", name);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx) instance passed to the CellClick event handler has a [ColumnIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex.aspx) property, which you can check to see if the click came from the button column.

Like this:

```
private void dgv_buttonCol(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 4) // Change to the index of your button column
        {
             return;
        }

        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            string name = Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
            ShowRichMessageBox("Code", name);
        }
}
```

For the second part of your question, I'm not sure what you mean but you could certainly change the row height, perhaps using in the SelectionChanged event, or if you want to do something more in depth see ["How to: Customize the Appearance of Rows in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85kxk29c.aspx)

Comment: :Could you please point out and tell me in the code. Give me more...please.

Comment: tried your solution but this time no display `ShowRichMessageBox`. the button position is in the 9nth column

Comment: When you click the button, what is the value of e.ColumnIndex ?

Comment: @ Stuart Dunkeld:Before code there is date column, so the button view is right after `depth unit` and the value i need is the `code`

Comment: @linguini So are you getting the value from the wrong column?

Comment: It works fine, as you mentioned it. I forgot that the index value of the button is `0` because it's dynamic. And i want to get the range from -1.